# Recreating the self signed certificate of vmware esxi server

Tags: certificate, vmware-workstation, esxi

I have installed vmware esxi server in vmware workstation on my machine.

In general it takes one ip addresses of dhcp configuration.It has the server cerification.In otherwords to call the server `https://10.100.13.36` is the format we should use.

can we recreate the certificate of that server.(Because every vmware server takes the same certificate..i guess)
my machine ip address is 10.100.13.113
can we recreate the certificate from my machine(i.e from 10.100.13.113)(java program or with any other tool)

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solution on my own with the help of vmware community suggestions.
In general if we want to change the certificate, we have lot of ways to do.
But the simple way is to go to `/sbin/generate-certificates.sh` execution.

Once we have done this, the regeneration of certifictate takes place. To effect the changes reboot the machine with the command `reboot`

To change the key length of the private key,

```
chmod 777 generate-certicates.sh
vi generate-certificates.sh
```

Type <kbd>i</kbd> and go to line where key length is mentioned. Change to 1024.
To set a password, chnage `encrypt key :no` to `encrypt key: yes`

<kbd>esc</kbd>

To close vi and save your changes, type `:x`

Then go to intial root and execute by typing `/sbin/generate-certificates.sh`
Then `reboot`